# Adobe Air - can you use a multitouch event instead of a mouse event to drag a native window?

Tags: air, adobe

I am looking to use the nativeWindow.startMove() to drag the chrome around, but with a touchEvent rather than a mouse event. I'm not sure if this is at all possible after extensive googling.

I have also tried to dispatch manual mouseEvents when a touchEvent is fired.

Ultimately is the startMove function strictly a mouse only driven function, or can I force this to occur through a touchEvent?

Any input would be most grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change x and y properties of the NativeWindow in response to TouchEvents, not necessary using startMove().